# Parsing XML file etree module

Tags: python, xml

I'm reading XML file using Etree module. Im using following code to print the value of `<page>` and `<title>` tags. My code working fine. But I want little change. If the `<page id='...'>`  attribute id is exists then print the value of tag. Is it possible? thanks

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
from pprint import pprint
tree = etree.parse('find_title.xml')
for value in tree.getiterator(tag='title'):
    print value.text
for value in tree.getiterator(tag='page'):
    pprint(value.attrib)
```

Here is my xml File.

```
 <mediawiki>
      <siteinfo>
        <sitename>Wiki</sitename>
        <namespaces>
          <namespace key="-2" case="first-letter">Media</namespace>
        </namespaces>
      </siteinfo>
    <page id="31239628" orglength="6822" newlength="4524" stub="0" categories="0" outlinks="1" urls="10">
    <title>Title</title>
    <categories></categories>
    <links>15099779</links>
    <urls>
    </urls>
    <text>

    Books

    </text>
    </page>

    </mediawiki>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for el in tree.getiterator(tag='page'):
    page_id = el.get('id', None) # returns second arg if id not exists
    if page_id:
        print page_id, el.find('title').text
    else:
        pprint(el.attrib)
```

**Edit:**  Updated for commment: "Thanks can i print page_id and title at same time? Means 31239628 - Title"

Comment: Thanks can i print `page_id` and `title` at same time? Means `31239628 - Title`

Answer (score 1):

The *element.get()* method is used to retrieve option attribute values in a tag:

```
>>> page_id = tree.find('page').get('id')
>>> if page_id:
        print page_id

31239628
```